# GCM Push Notification adobe air

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air, google-cloud-messaging

I m developing a push notification service for my app in android  i came to some tutorials to achieve my goal. I struck to 2 things that i can't figure out. I need some help.

- PushNotifications.init( "*DEV_KE*Y" );
- `<permission
  android:name="*application ID*.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"`

Now i want to know about this 2 things. Dev_key and application id.Secondly is PushNotifications.init(); necessary to call? what if i call it without dev_key param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're following the tutorials on distriqt's site about using the distriqt cross platform push notifications extension?

If so then the **DEV_KEY** is actually the developer key you get when you sign up to the distriqt extension package. It is necessary to call this function with a valid key if you are hoping to use the distriqt extensions. If you call it without the DEV_KEY param the extension will not work as documented.

The second line you have there containing the *application ID* is used in your application descriptor file. You need to add the following to your manifest additions on android replacing all the YOUR_APPLICATION_ID references with your applications id. This is normally of the form : com.company.name. The **air** prefixes are shown as these are your applications full id on the Android platform.

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">

            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

            <!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result --> 
            <permission android:name="air.YOUR_APPLICATION_ID.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
            <uses-permission android:name="air.YOUR_APPLICATION_ID.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

            <application>
                <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.distriqt.extension.pushnotifications.PushNotificationsBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                        <category android:name="air.YOUR_APPLICATION_ID" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.distriqt.extension.pushnotifications.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
            </application>

        </manifest>

    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```